# import static: 'MainController' is not a symbol that can be resolved

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I have a class that I want to import a public static method (getModPart()) from. The source of getModePart() is the MainController. Here are the relevant definitions in MainController:

**MainController**

```
public class MainController implements Initializable
{

// ...

// Variable declared globally:

private static Part currentModPart;

// Functions that use the above variable:

public static Part getModPart() 
{
   return currentModPart;
}

public static void setModifiedPart(Part modifyPart) 
{
   MainController.currentModPart = modifyPart;
}
```

Then the class that I am trying to import the MainController.getModPart to has the following:

**ModifyPartController**

```
// various import statements, including the one below. In the import statement below, IntelliJ highlights 
// only the MainController text below in red, and hovering the cursor over it reveals a message, 
// "Cannot resolve symbol MainController"'

import static View_Controller.MainController.getModPart;


// Below is the code that involves the getModPart() function that I want to use from MainController

private Part modifiedPart;
    
public ModifyPartController()
{
   modifiedPart = getModPart();
}
```

So I don't get why the MainController would not be importable. What should I look for to rule out some possible causes?

Comment: You need to seriously rethink your object design here. You should not be using static methods or imports here. Instead, pass a reference to your `MainController` to the `ModifyPartController`. I would recommend some basic Java/JavaFX and OOP tutorials to get a grasp on these concepts.

Comment: Static _state_ (anything that can be modified, like your `modifiedPart`), is a serious design flag.

Answer (score 0):

My thesis is that Jetbrains IDEs can't find the actual type definition for Controller because Stimulus just does export * from "@stimulus/core", and the IDE can't follow the indirection to find the actual controller.d.ts in the @stimulus/core library.

Obviously not perfect for IntelliSense, but your bundler should still compile it just fine

Comment: Oh wow, you're right, it actually does compile. The program actually functions like it's supposed to, despite the error message.